# Post a form into an iframe on another page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a page from a 3rdparty I want to post to another page into an iframe so that tha layout is maintained. 
So i have host.com/pageA. This contains the form

host.com/pageB This contains the iframe

vendor.com/reallyComplicatedUrlthatSoundsFancyButMeansNothing

I want to post the results from pageA to pageB where the pageB contains the iframe into which the results are posted.

Target=iframe doesn't work since the iframe is on another page.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will have to be done in combination of server and client code. Something like...

**PageA.php**

```
<form action="PageB.php" method="post">
    <input name="field1">
    <input name="field2">
    <input type="hidden" name="PageAToPageB" value="SomeString">
</form>
```

**PageB.php**

```
<?php 
    if ($_POST["PageAToPageB"] == "SomeString")
    {
?>
        <form id="PageAToPageBForm" target="iFrameName" method="post">
            <input name="field1" value="<?= $_POST['field1'] ?>">
            <input name="field2" value="<?= $_POST['field2'] ?>">
        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $("#PageAToPageBForm").submit();
        });
        </script>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the only way is using GET method, like:

```
<iframe src="host.com/pageB?firstparm=1&secoundparm=2..."</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to "prepare" you parent page...try this way:

Your links in page A would be

`<a href="pageb.htm?iframepage1.htm">Iframe page 1</a>
<a href="pageb.htm?iframepage2.htm">Iframe page 2</a>`

In page B

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Document Title</TITLE>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

function loadIframe(){
if (location.search.length > 0){
url = unescape(location.search.substring(1))

window.frames["myiframe"].location=url
}
}

onload=loadIframe
//-->
</script>


</HEAD>
<BODY>


<iframe name="myiframe" id="myiframe" src=""></iframe>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```